# Bijective map from (0,1) to [0,1).

Tags: real-analysis

I couldn't find a Bijective map from (0,1) to [0,1). Is there any example?

Comment: $1/2\mapsto0, 3/4\mapsto1/2, 7/8\mapsto 3/4,...$ and everything else maps to itself

Comment: Note that the proposed "duplicate" has $(0,1]$ where this question has $[0,1)$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner why would 3/4↦1/2,7/8↦3/4,...  ?

Comment: Since we map $1/2\mapsto0$, we need something to map to $1/2$; if we take $3/4$, then we need something to map to $3/4;\cdots$